# Searchkit Buttons not working

Tags: shoreditch, bootstrap, apiv4, searchkit

Using beta version of SearchKit. Buttons for Add, Compose Search and AND,OR,Not options are not working/unresponsive.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Problem a result of using Shoreditch as Civi theme.     Same problem exhibited when using API Explorer UI.

SearchKit and API Explorer both use bootstrap theme which seems to have conflict with Shoreditch.

Only solution found was to uninstall Shoreditch.    (Disabling shoreditch was not sufficient)

Comment: Upgrade shoreditch to version CiviCRM Bootstrap theme: Version 1.0.0-beta.4 seems to solve problem